# Failed when installing Redis on Ubuntu 22.04 (Failed to start Advanced key-value store.)

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, redis

I always failed installed Redis on ubuntu 22.04 (AWS EC2 instance) with the following errors as shown below:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-41-151:~$ systemctl status redis-server.service
× redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2024-02-23 08:58:04 UTC; 2min 52s ago
       Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
             man:redis-server(1)
    Process: 1596 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Main PID: 1596 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
     Status: "Redis is loading..."
        CPU: 80ms

Feb 23 08:58:04 ip-172-31-41-151 systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 23 08:58:04 ip-172-31-41-151 systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 23 08:58:04 ip-172-31-41-151 systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
Feb 23 08:58:04 ip-172-31-41-151 systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Feb 23 08:58:04 ip-172-31-41-151 systemd[1]: Stopped Advanced key-value store.
Feb 23 08:58:04 ip-172-31-41-151 systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Feb 23 08:58:04 ip-172-31-41-151 systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 23 08:58:04 ip-172-31-41-151 systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
```

I follow the instructions of installation from Redis officially.

```
curl -fsSL https://packages.redis.io/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg

echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/redis-archive-keyring.gpg] https://packages.redis.io/deb $(lsb_release -cs) main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/redis.list

sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install redis
```

but it always failed.

I don't know how to solve this problem. Please help how to fix this error. Thank you.

I tried to follow some solutions from several source to fix the problem but nothing work.